# How can I explicitly specify the Web.config XML Transformation in a Web Deploy pubxml file?

Tags: web-config, web-deployment, msdeploy, web.config-transform

Web Deployment and `*.pubxml` files in Visual Studio have a neat feature that allows `web.config` XML Transformations to be applied at Deploy Time, not just Build Time, which enables per-deployment (i.e. per-environment) `web.config` customizations.

Problem is, the transformation happens "by magic" - if you have a file in your website root named `web.{profile name}.config` then it will be applied during publish - but you have no way of disabling this functionality, or (as far as I can tell) specifying a different transformation file. I also cannot see how you can transform other web.config files (such as the `Views/web.config` file in an MVC project) using `pubxml` files.

I did notice that `pubxml` files are just MSBuild XML files in their own right - so clearly the Deploy process is just a matter of executing those MSBuild files with the right targets - so to get the functionality I want, I just need to modify the `pubxml` file with my own custom build-steps.

...but how should I add those build-steps? What is the extensibility-point and event to target?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but you should be able to create a package and exclude the web.config file from it.  Then you could run the transform yourself (slow cheetah or something else) and specify that you want the transformed file deployed with the package when msdeploy deploys it.  This would be done in the call to the generated cmd or in the manual call to msdeploy.  Either way it ends up getting put in the call to msdeploy.  I haven't done this myself yet, but theoretically it should be possible since you can explicitly pass in additional files to deploy

Answer (score 0):

Pubxml configuration still happens at build time it just assumes you will deploy at the same time as well and allows you to adjust your config accordingly.

If you want true deploy-time configuration changes you should use WebDeploy parameterization. It is much more capable and is applied when the WebDeploy package is deployed.

We use it for 50+ product deployments to 4 different environments (DEV, QA, MOCK, PROD) with great success.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: To my knowledge, Web Deploy parameterisation does not allow for the level of transformation allowed by XDT, and that's why you can run both in MSBuild.

Comment: We converted 50+ applications from config transforms to parameterization and found parameterization was more capable.